# Is there an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) framework that supports C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, sql, database

I'm looking for an ORM that will allow me to write a C# user interface and a C++ service. Both need to access data from the same database. Ideally I want C# and C++ classes to be generated from the database schema that I can then program against.

The database will probably be SQLServer, but that hasn't been decided yet.

Note: I'm doing this in a windows environment, but for reasons I don't want to go into, I can't actually use COM, so a COM solution isn't an option.

This is similar to this question:

[ORM (object relational manager) solution with multiple programming language support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482612/orm-object-relational-manager-solution-with-multiple-programming-language-suppo)

However, that wasn't answered well enough, and I can't raise a bounty on it.

Comment: Voting to close. It is an exact duplicate. The only difference is you didn't like the answers.

Comment: That related question covered Python which is not something I need an ORM for. I resisted opening my question and would have raised a bounty on the existing one if it was possible to put a bounty on another persons question.

Comment: Thanks for being polite enough to comment on your reason for closing. I agree it is a very similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this may not be of any help to you, but if you give up on trying to find a pre-build solution, it's not that terribly difficult to develop an in-house version that only supports what you need.

We have an in-house data definition language that we use to generate the SQL schema for our data, and ORM classes for native C++ and .NET.  The only real trick is comparing the generated schema with what's already in the database to make migrations to the next version easier.

Comment: Thanks, that is very useful! We have got an in house system for generating C++ and C# classes that can be serialized into the same format. I was considering extending this system for database mappings. Before I did though, I wanted to be sure there wasn't something already suitable that would save me some time. I doesn't look like it so far.